# Shouldn't poison message services handle generic messages?

Tags: wcf, msmq

Okay, so I've been trying to wrap my head around queue -> dead-letter queue -> poison subqueue of dead-letter queue -> ?

Now, as far [as I understand](http://www.cogin.com/articles/SurvivingPoisonMessages.php), messages can be sent to the poison queue if they fail processing **or if the Action on the message is not supported by the receiver**.  [Most of the articles I've found](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789028.aspx) show implementing the poison service with the same contract as the main service.  Wouldn't that *put a message poisonous to the poison message queue **into** the poison message queue* if the error is that the contract doesn't support the message provided?

Wouldn't it make more sense to have a handler that can handle anything in the poison queue?  The below assumes a WCF Message, which probably isn't safe either (and is completely untested), but is there a way to have fool-proof poison queue handling?  The more I try to think through the edge cases with queueing, the more I feel that it's impossible to have a complete system that handles all possibilities.

```
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
    [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete = true)]
    public void CatchAll(Message message)
    {
        // Log somewhere?
    }
```

Another thought is to have a trigger that moves all messages from the poison queue back into the dead-letter queue to be handled again - which will probably poison again and loop infinitely.

I guess the specific question is.. how do people handle poison messages in a dead-letter queue?  And the general question is - how the heck do you handle all situations in MSMQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I was aware, the `MsmqMessage<T>` type can be used in concert with any of the WCF msmq bindings.

So if you specify an recieve type of `MsmqMessage<String>` this should cover all bases. You will receive the message as a string. How you handle what is in the string is another story...

Comment: So are you saying not to bother implementing the original contract?

Comment: In your poison handler yes.